# Get index of element in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, dom, indexing, element

I have this code:

```
        //Callback function
        var done = arguments[arguments.length - 1]; 
        //Take all the events
        var array_events = []

        var retour = (e) => {
            array_events.push(e.target.outerHTML)
        }

        var quit = (key) => {
            console.log(array_events);
            (key.keyCode == 27 )? done(JSON.stringify(array_events)) : undefined
        }
        // Listen to the clicks
        getPath = document.addEventListener("click", retour, true)
        getIndex = document.addEventListener("click", detour, true)
        // Listen to the key "esc" which means user has gathered all needed events
        getKey = document.addEventListener("keydown", quit, true)
```

This gets me the value of outerHTML of an element clicked, so far so good.
I'm building a program that needs to find that element,but in the case where the outerHTML of the element is not unique (meaning there are multiple occurrences of that element in the DOM), I cannot find out which one of the elements the user wants, so I think the easiest way would be to include index of some sort.

**My question is ->**
How can I get the index of that element relative to whole HTML document?
If that is not possible, any index of some sort that I can take and calculate which one is first or second or last does help too!

Comment: Where do you get multiple elements? The outerHTML of one specific element is always unique. One element can't have multiple different outerHTMLs. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: If an element has an id, you can access it in JS easily just via `element.id`, so in your case: `e.target.id`. In any case, by what you're describing seems like you want to heavily rely on id's and comparison of outerHTML's to help manage the user's experience. This can work, but are you doing this to avoid having more lines in Javascript? I don't know how you're rendering the content, but ultimately it would be best if everything is defined-and-tracked in JS. IMHO, element id's are best used for UI elements and not pieces of data.

Comment: In other words, you're dealing with "state management" and it's your reason to be getting into React or Vue. You can do it from scratch too of course.

Comment: I would use data-id when creating the divs to identify them, but if you can't do that, you can use something like this:

[...document.querySelectorAll(event.target.tagName.toLocaleLowerCase())].indexOf(teevent.target)

To find the index of the item in the whole body ( feel free to change the querySelector parent ) 

PS: I have not tested this, but it may not be reliable, it may be better to run a function that adds data-id on document load and use that instead =)

Comment: @ithan i like your idea of getting the count from the result of querySelectorAll. Unfortunatly it will not work as in your example because we do not have indexOf in the result form querySelectorAll, since it is a NodeLsit not array. That said it is still doable, and i beleve it will be very reliable especially if you are using some specific class instead of tag name, since performance can be a problem if you are searching for a "div" for example.

Answer (score -1):

I am not aware of any indexing of DOM elements that is accessible with JS.
Not sure how you want to use this information about what element has been selected. So here are several ideas, hope one will be useful.

1. If you need to do something with that element, like modify it in some way in your callback, then you may want to use:

   e.target.parentElement

This will return the actual DOM element, and you can do whatever you want with it. It does not matter how many copies you have in the page. And if you actually need the HTML text, you can always use .innerHTML to get it.

2. If you need this for some type of analytics where you want to save this interaction somewhere instead of modifying the page you can do something like this:

   e.target.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect()

This will return an object that looks something like this:
[image]

this way you will know the exact coordinates of the element that was selected, and even if you have multiple elements with the exact same HTML you can know that this is some specific copy of it.

3. If you do not have too many elements that need to be affected by this, maybe you can add the index yourself. When all elements are created, you can do something like this:

```js
let maxId = 0;
const allElements = document.querySelectorAll('.SelectorForYourElement');
allElements.forEach(element => {
  element.dataset.id = ++maxId;
});
```

Comment: The title is _"Get the index of element in HTML"_. The question is _"How can I get the index of that element relative to whole HTML document?"_ Where do I find this in your answer?

Comment: @jabaa option 3 dose exactly that. If you have added the id before, than you can literally see/get it at any point where you have the element. And you can get the element as i have described in option 1. Also option 2 is there, because "Get index of element in HTML"  is very generic way of asking the question, and it can be understood in multiple ways.

Comment: But the OP didn't add the ID. They are asking, how to get the index. Option 3 isn't dynamic.